# How to input a variable value to launch.json configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't always need a debugger running, but when I need to **attach** the PID is different every time and I need to edit launch.json.  Editing the launch.json works but not ideal because I have to look up the pid, and it's a pita.

So how do I load that value into the launch.json? with a .env variable, or even with an input prompt?

The documentation here seems to say that is possible 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

In launch.json I have tried prompting for input with the following configuration

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach by Process ID",
        "processId": "${input:debugPid}"
    },

"inputs": [
    {
        "id": "debugPid",
        "description": "enter the pid number",
        "type": "promptString",
        "default": "1234"
    }
]
```

When I use the `pickNodeProcess` command extension `"processId": "${command:extension.pickNodeProcess}"` but the debug port is set to 9229 and does not connect

I've also tried setting processId to an .env variable `"processId": "${env:DEBUG_PID}"`

The PID value that works when editing the config is available on the console log like this, and set as a .env variable.

```
process.env.DEBUG_PID = process.pid; 
console.log(`DEBUG_PID:${process.env.DEBUG_PID}`)
```

What ever I try `"processId": "whatever"` seems to type checked as a pid before the input.  Is this a bug then?